# How to partition vector of results in Rust?

Tags: rust

Basically, I'm looking for the [partitionEithers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:partitionEithers) equivalent in Rust, i.e. to convert `Vec<Result<A, B>>` into `Result<Vec<A>, Vec<B>>`.

I know I can transform a `Vec<Result<A, B>>` into `Result<Vec<A>, B>` by using `collect::<Result<Vec<A>, B>>`, but when I try `collect::<Result<Vec<A>, Vec<B>>>`, I'll get an error saying such implementation is missing.

Also I know this can be done using mutations, but I'm wondering if there are any immutable alternatives that I can look into?

Comment: The `partitionEithers` equivalent in Rust would be a `fn(Vec<Result<A, B>>) -> (Vec<A>, Vec<B>)` -- note that `Result` is an enum, and `Result<Vec<A>, Vec<B>>` can contain _either_ a `Vec<A>` _or_ a `Vec<B>` but not both.

Comment: @Stargateur can you explain why it does not make sense?

Comment: The expected error type is `Vec<B>`

Comment: oh I must have been tired yesterday :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can *partition* by using the [`partition()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) method, on your particular case, use [`partition_map()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) from itertools:

```rust
use itertools::{Either, Itertools};
fn main() {
    let successes_and_failures = vec![Ok(1), Err(false), Err(true), Ok(2)];

    let (successes, failures): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) =
        successes_and_failures
            .into_iter()
            .partition_map(|r| match r {
                Ok(v) => Either::Left(v),
                Err(v) => Either::Right(v),
            });

    assert_eq!(successes, [1, 2]);
    assert_eq!(failures, [false, true]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have adopted `itertools` earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The `itertools` crate has a dedicated method for partitioning an `Iterator<Item = Result<T, E>>` into a tuple of collections `(Collection<T>, Collection<E>)`, where "Collection" can be your choice of type that implements the `Extend` trait, such as `Vec` or `HashSet`.

https://docs.rs/itertools/0.11.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_result

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let successes_and_failures = vec![Ok(1), Err(false), Err(true), Ok(2)];

    let (successes, failures): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) =
        successes_and_failures.into_iter().partition_result();

    assert_eq!(successes, [1, 2]);
    assert_eq!(failures, [false, true]);
}
```

For more generality in the situation that your iterator's `Item` type is not exactly `Result` but something else, there is also [`partition_map`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.11.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_result) where you can provide a closure with your own logic for deciding whether each element belongs in the first or second output collection.